# modernizr todataurljpeg is asynchronous, how to use?

Tags: modernizr

[Modernizr's test](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/pull/470) for canvas-todataurl-type has a comment:

```
// This test is asynchronous. Watch out.
```

So.. what is the best practice for knowing when it is safe to use this test.  I see it loads in an image, but the library does not look like it offers any callbacks for when to test.

Comment: I think the general ideal is that if you test it "a while later" you'll be fine.

Comment: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/622

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*@jedierikb - I think you know the answer, as you helped us with this! But for the sake of others...*

In Modernizr 2.x, it takes a little bit of manual work. Async detects will be `undefined` until they complete, so...:

```
<script src="path/to/modernizr.js"></script>
<script>
  (function withDataURL () {
    if (typeof Modernizr.todataurljpeg !== 'undefined') {
      // Do things with `Modernizr.todataurljpeg`
    }
    else {
      setTimeout(withDataURL, 100);
    }
  }());
</script>
```

Alternatively, use a watch library/shim/plugin, e.g. https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583

In Modernizr 3.0, we're making 2 relevant changes:

- Canvas `todataurl` detects are all synchronous (thanks to @jedierikb)
- Other synchronous detects will have first-class support, probably with callbacks (we're still working out the finer details of this)